# In Swift is it possible to write a function that receives another function and its parameters to later execute it when appropriate?

Tags: swift, generics

Let’s say I have this function

```swift
func executeFunction<Value>(_ function: (Any...) -> Value, params: Any...) -> Value {
    //some pre processing before the function is executed
    return function(params)
}
```

And I want it to be able to receive any type of function with any number of parameters with just the condition of it to return something.
Like, ie:

```swift
func greetUser(_ user: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(user)"
}

executeFunction(greetUser, params: "John Doe")
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind! I found how.
Turns out I needed to specify the arguments of the `function` and the type of the argument `params` as `T`.

```swift
func executeFunction<Value, T>(_ function: (T) -> Value, params: T = () as! T) -> Value {
    //some pre processing before the function is executed
    return function(params)
}
```

This way I was able to invoke the `executeFunction` with three different functions each having different number of parameters.

```swift
func greetUser(_ user: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(user)"
}

func add(_ num1: Int, to num2: Int) -> Int {
    return num1 + num2
}

let string = executeFunction(greetUser, params: "John Doe") // -> "Hello John Doe"
let result = executeFunction(add, params: (1,2))            // -> 3
let hello = executeFunction(sayHello)                       // -> "Hello"
```